# Tooltip для Label

Tags: wpf, c#

Подскажите, как правильно сделать tooltip для label, содержащий такой же текст как и сам label?

PS Текст label'a устанавливается динамически.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, автор хотел решение на подобие этого:

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock 
        Text="{Binding Path=SomeValue}" 
        ToolTip="{Binding Text, RelativeSource {RelativeSource Self}}"
    />
</Label>
```

Comment: Биндинги ужасно читаются..неестественный синтаксис. Авторам фи :)

Answer (score 3):

Подписаться на событие TextChanged и в обработчие написать

```
private void m_label_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var label = sender as Label;

  if (label == null)
    return;

  label.ToolTip = label.Text;
}
```

Comment: Это подход из WinForms, а хотелось бы сделать средствами WPF.

Comment: @Jones, у вас чисто академический интерес к реализации именно "средствами WPF" или реальная задача такая стоит?

Comment: @Jones Что значит средствами WPF? Какой у вас паттерн? MVVC? MVC? MVP? Вот ему и следуйте. С точки зрения MVP/MVC, например, код выше - с некоторой точки зрения нарушения, хотя и не является катастрофой. Для MVVC это тоже не корзинка цветов, то мне кажется, что это тоже допустимо, хотя и странно.

Comment: MVP/MVC - отнюдь не универсальное архитектурное решение для пользовательского интерфейса. Оно хорошо, когда на форме много простых элементов управления, сложно связанных друг с другом поведением. Но у нас, например, куча формочек автоматически рисуется по объектной модели. Для таких формочек выделение абстрагированного от реализации UI слоя не оправдано. А фраза "Text устанавливается динамически" наводит о мысль именно о таком классе задач.